How to efficiently traverse trait implementation graphs in Rust?
I have just started learning Rust, read some books, did rustlings, and now to get some experience I'm looking through Rust projects, trying to understand their code, and often I see code like this:
fn execute_test() {
    let my_struct = MyStruct { value: 42 };

    use_trait_one(my_struct);
}

fn use_trait_one<T: TraitOne>(target: T) {
    target.do_something();
}

trait TraitOne {
    fn do_something(&self);
}

trait TraitTwo {
    fn do_something_ex(&self);
}

trait TraitThree {
    fn do_something(&self);
}

trait TraitFour {
    fn do_something(&self);
}

struct MyStruct {
    value: i32,
}

impl TraitFour for MyStruct {
    fn do_something(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.value);
    }
}

impl<T: TraitFour> TraitThree for T {
    fn do_something(&self) {
        self.do_something();
    }
}

impl<T: TraitFour> TraitTwo for T {
    fn do_something_ex(&self) {
        self.do_something();
    }
}

impl<T: TraitTwo + TraitFour + Send + Sync + 'static> TraitOne for T {
    fn do_something(&self) {
        self.do_something();
        self.do_something_ex();
    }
}

Is there a quick automated way (IDE, rustc, third-party tools?) to traverse this directed trait implementation graph, if I want to find out how "MyStruct" implements "TraitOne"?
It is pretty hard to do this manually, because these trait implementations may come from different modules and packages.

rust-analyzer can find all implementations of a specific trait.

Using rustdoc (for example, on docs.rs), the most efficient way to go about this would be:

Open the type you are interested in (MyStruct) and the trait you know it implements (TraitOne).
See if MyStruct is mentioned in the implementations of TraitOne. If MyStruct is a dependency of TraitOne, then instead, check if TraitOne is mentioned in the implementations of MyStruct. If yes, this is the end of the graph. Otherwise, continue.
Go to the blanket implementations of TraitOne. This says impl<T: TraitTwo + TraitFour + Send + Sync + 'static> TraitOne for T. One at a time, repeat steps 2 and 3 for each bound. They need to all connect to MyStruct, so you can only look through some of them if you want.

In this case, Send + Sync + 'static are all true of MyStruct directly, so those end immediately. 'static isn't mentioned in rustdoc but you can tell it is true since MyStruct has no lifetimes. Send and Sync appear in MyStruct's auto trait implementations section.
TraitTwo has a blanket implementation using TraitFour. TraitFour is implemented explicitly for MyStruct.
Going back to T: TraitTwo + TraitFour + Send + Sync + 'static, TraitFour is the only one left, and we just looked at that one in TraitTwo's path.
In simple cases this will be enough. However if you are trying to see why a trait method is callable, then you will need to consider any of the types that method resolution can access. That means checking for &MyStruct, &mut MyStruct, and if MyStruct implements Deref, the deref target type of MyStruct, plus all of those recursively. Traits are also allowed to have blanket implementations of T, &T, and &mut T, but fortunately, they are only allowed one blanket implementation of each wrapper. Generics in the type and the trait will also make this more complicated, and type aliases will not help. I don't think I'll ever know what traits sha2::Sha256 implements.
For a real world example, say you have the trait rand::Rng and rand_xoshiro::Xoshiro256StarStar.

Open the implementations of Rng: https://docs.rs/rand/latest/rand/trait.Rng.html#implementors Open the implementations of Xoshiro256StarStar: https://docs.rs/rand_xoshiro/latest/rand_xoshiro/struct.Xoshiro256StarStar.html#trait-implementations
Xoshiro256StarStar doesn't mention Rng, so continue.
Look at the blanket implementation of Rng: impl<R: RngCore + ?Sized> Rng for R. It requires RngCore, so go to the docs for RngCore.
Xoshiro256StarStar does implement RngCore. The search is complete.

The path found was Xoshiro256StarStar -> RngCore -> Rng.
